# Render API response with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration

I am trying to render the response of a simple api I've created but when I try to iterate through the items, it comes as undefined. I know it has to do with asynchronous programming but can't figure out how to solve it. Could anybody help ?

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: undefined
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://petzie-cajuhqnpqy.now.sh/breeds')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    items: data.result
                };
            });
            console.log(this.state);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>    
                { this.state.items.map((item) => {
                    return <p>{item.name}</p>;
                }) }         
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are going to `.map` through `this.state.items`, it can't be undefined at any point, otherwise you will throw an error (`.map` expects an array). So, in your constructor, define it as an empty array:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] };
}
```

Second, `setState` is async. Therefore, when you call `setState` and `this.state` right after it, the object was not updated yet. But because of React nature, whenever it gets updated, your render function will be called again and this time `this.state.items` will have the data fetched from the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael, that was the only change I had to make in order to have it work. And thanks for the setState advice also. Cheers !

Comment: You're welcome. Please just accept the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have async calls you need to do something like this:

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.items) { 
        return <div></div> 
    }
    return (
        <div>    
            { this.state.items.map((item) => {
                return <p>{item.name}</p>;
            }) }         
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is one way to do it.

Comment: You forgot the `!` before `this.state.items`. Anyways this is not necessary if you initially set `this.state.items` to `[]`. A call to `map()` on an empty array will not do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, that also possible